# Limit of integral $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{\cos x}^{1}{}\arctan t ^2\ \mathrm dt}{\tan^2 x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{\cos x}^{1}{}\arctan t
^2\ \mathrm dt}{\tan^2 x}$$

There is a part of the answer written as

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_{\cos x}^{1}{}\arctan t
^2\ \mathrm dt=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\tan^2 x=0$$

How do you even come to this conclusion?

Comment: Substitute x=0 into the above equation and you have 0 in the numerator and 0 in the denominator. So you have a indeterminate form 0/0.

Comment: oh ok so you use L'Hospital for this problem?

Comment: @pmac You can use l'Hopital's rule because you have an indeterminate form 0/0. That's precisely what you've written in line 2.

Comment: I was never satisfied with the L'Hospital rules, as easy as they are. Thus, I like @MarkViola's non-L'Hospital solution. Either way you look at it, it is a nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

Note that for $x\in (-\pi/4,\pi/4)$, we have

$$(1-\cos(x))\arctan(\cos^2(x))\le \int_{\cos(x)}^1 \arctan(t^2)\,dt\le (1-\cos(x))\frac\pi4$$

Hence, we assert that

$$ \frac{1-\cos(x)}{\tan^2(x)}\arctan(\cos^2(x))\le \frac{\int_{\cos(x)}^1 \arctan(t^2)\,dt}{\tan^2(x)}\le \frac\pi4 \frac{1-\cos(x)}{\tan^2(x)}$$

whence using $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\tan^2(x)}=\frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$ and applying of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{\cos(x)}^1 \arctan(t^2)\,dt}{\tan^2(x)}=\frac\pi8$$

Comment: $(1-\cos(x))\arctan(\cos^2(x))\le \int_{\cos(x)}^1 \arctan(t^2)\,dt\le (1-\cos(x))\frac\pi4$ how do you come to this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: They first check whether L'Hospital rule is applicable.

Since $\lim_{x\to 0} \tan^2 x = 0$ they need to check first whether 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_{\cos x}^{1}\arctan t
^2\mathrm dt=0$, as well.

This is so, since $\arctan t^2$ is continuous and, hence, you have $0\leq \arctan t^2 \leq M$ for $t\in\left[\frac 12,1\right]$, for example. So, for $0 \leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{3}$  (note that $\cos \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac 12$) you have $\cos x \in \left[\frac 12,1\right]$ and hence
$$0\leq \int_{\cos x}^{1}\arctan t
^2\mathrm dt\leq M(1-\cos x) \stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Now, L'Hospital gives

\begin{eqnarray}\frac{\int_{\cos x}^{1}{}\arctan t
^2\mathrm dt}{\tan^2 x} 
& \stackrel{L'Hosp.}{\sim} & \frac{-\arctan \cos^2 x \cdot (-\sin x)}{2\frac{\sin x}{\cos^3 x}} \\& = & \frac 12 \cos^3 x\arctan \cos^2 x\\
& \stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow} &\frac 12 \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{8}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'Hospital and the fundamental theorem of calculus since
$$\frac d {dx} \int_{a(x)}^1 f(t)\,dt=-f(a(x))\, a'(x)$$ So, for your case, using  L'Hospital once, we arrive at $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{\cos (x)}^{1}{}\arctan (t
^2)\mathrm dt}{\tan^2 x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{2} \cos ^3(x) \tan ^{-1}\left(\cos ^2(x)\right)\right)=\frac \pi 8$$

*Added for your curiosity.*

It happens that the antiderivative has a closed form expression (try Wolfram Alpha for it).
Using the bounds and Taylor expansions, we should have as a result
$$\frac{\pi }{8}-\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{3 \pi }{32}\right)
   x^2+\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{\pi }{64}\right) x^4+O\left(x^6\right)$$